# How to connect to mongoDB and test for drop collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, jestjs

This is how I connect to a mongoDB using `monk()`. I'll store it in `state`.

Assume we want to drop some collections, we call `dropDB`.

**db.js**

```
var state = {
  db: null
}

export function connection () {
  if (state.db) return
  state.db = monk('mongdb://localhost:27017/db')
  return state.db
}

export async function dropDB () {
  var db = state.db
  if (!db) throw Error('Missing database connection')

  const Users = db.get('users')
  const Content = db.get('content')

  await Users.remove({})
  await Content.remove({})
}
```

I'm not quite sure if it is a good approach to use `state` variable. Maybe someone can comment on that or show an improvement.

Now I want to write a unit test for this function using JestJS:

**db.test.js**

```
import monk from 'monk'
import { connection, dropDB } from './db'
jest.mock('monk')

describe('dropDB()', () => {
  test('should throw error if db connection is missing', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    await expect(dropDB()).rejects.toEqual(Error('Missing database connection'))
  })
})
```

This part is easy, but the next part gives me two problems:

How do I mock the `remove()` methods?

```
  test('should call remove() methods', async () => {
    connection() // should set `state.db`, but doesn't work
    const remove = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ n: 1, nRemoved: 1, ok: 1 }))
    // How do I use this mocked remove()?
    expect(remove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
  })
```

And before that? How do I setup `state.db`?

---

**Update**

As explained by *poke* the global variable makes the problem. So I switched to a class:

**db.js**

```
export class Db {
  constructor() {
    this.connection = monk('mongdb://localhost:27017/db');
  }

  async dropDB() {
    const Users = this.connection.get('users');
    const Content = this.connection.get('content');

    await Users.remove({});
    await Content.remove({});
  }
}
```

which results in this test file:

**db.test.js**

```
import { Db } from './db'
jest.mock('./db')

let db
let remove

describe('DB class', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const remove = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ n: 1, nRemoved: 1, ok: 1 }))
    Db.mockImplementation(() => {
      return { dropDB: () => {
        // Define this.connection.get() and use remove as a result of it
      } }
    })
  })
  describe('dropDB()', () => {
    test('should call remove method', () => {
      db = new Db()
      db.dropDB()
      expect(remove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
    })
  })
})
```

How do I mock out any `this` elements? In this case I need to mock `this.connection.get()`

Comment: are you calling the connection? I don't see a call to "connect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a global state is definitely the source of your problem here. I would suggest to look for a solution that does not involve global variables at all. As per [Global Variables Are Bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad), global variables cause tight coupling and make things difficult to test (as you have noticed yourself).

A better solution would be to either pass the database connection explicitly to the `dropDB` function, so it has the connection as an *explicit dependency*, or to introduce some stateful object that holds onto the connection and offers the `dropDB` as a method.

The first option would look like this:

```
export function openConnection() {
  return monk('mongdb://localhost:27017/db');
}

export async function dropDB(connection) {
  if (!connection) {
    throw Error('Missing database connection');
  }

  const Users = connection.get('users');
  const Content = connection.get('content');

  await Users.remove({});
  await Content.remove({});
}
```

This would also make it *very easy* to test `dropDB` as you can now just pass a mocked object for it directly.

The other option could look like this:

```
export class Connection() {
  constructor() {
    this.connection = monk('mongdb://localhost:27017/db');
  }

  async dropDB() {
    const Users = this.connection.get('users');
    const Content = this.connection.get('content');

    await Users.remove({});
    await Content.remove({});
  }
}
```

---

A test for the first option could look like this:

```
test('should call remove() methods', async () => {
  const usersRemove = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(null));
  const contentRemove = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(null));
  const dbMock = {
    get(type) {
      if (type === 'users') {
        return { remove: usersRemove };
      }
      else if (type === 'content') {
        return { remove: contentRemove };
      }
    }
  };

  await dropDB(dbMock);

  expect(usersRemove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(contentRemove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Basically, the `dropDB` function expects an object that has a `get` method which when called returns an object that has a `remove` method. So you just need to pass *something* that looks like that, so the function can call those `remove` methods.

---

For the class, this is a bit more complicated since the constructor has a dependency on the `monk` module. One way would be to make that dependency explicit again (just like in the first solution), and pass `monk` or some other factory there. But we can also use [Jest’s manual mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) to simply mock the whole `monk` module.

Note that we do *not* want to mock the module containing our `Connection` type. We want to test that, so we need it in its un-mocked state.

To mock `monk`, we need to create a mock module of it at `__mocks__/monk.js`. The manual points out that this `__mocks__` folder should be adjacent to the `node_modules` folder.

In that file, we simply export our custom `monk` function. This is pretty much the same we already used in the first example, since we only care about getting those `remove` methods in place:

```
export default function mockedMonk (url) {
  return {
    get(type) {
      if (type === 'users') {
        return { remove: mockedMonk.usersRemove };
      }
      else if (type === 'content') {
        return { remove: mockedMonk.contentRemove };
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Note that this refers to the functions as `mockedMonk.usersRemove` and `mockedMonk.contentRemove`. We’ll use this in the test to configure those function explicitly during the test execution.

Now, in the test function, we need to call `jest.mock('monk')` to enable Jest to mock the `monk` module with our mocked module. Then, we can just import it too and set our functions within the test. Basically, just like above:

```
import { Connection } from './db';
import monk from 'monk';

// enable mock
jest.mock('./monk');

test('should call remove() methods', async () => {
  monk.usersRemove = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(null));
  monk.contentRemove = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(null));

  const connection = new Connection();
  await connection.dropDB();

  expect(monk.usersRemove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(monk.contentRemove).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: I’ve added an example test for the first solution. I haven’t really used Jest before, so I don’t know if that’s the best way to do it.

Comment: I've updated the post as I decided to switch to your solution using a class. But I get stuck with mocking out any `this` instances. Could you show me how to get this? Can I mock it at all or do I have to do it indirectly by mocking `monk()`?

Comment: @user3142695 Updated the post with a working test for the class-based solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation. It helped me very much to understand more details.